# Automatically save screenshot and copy file path to clipboard

Tags: clipboard, screenshot, application-launch

I have to use a bug report app where the only way to add an attachment is  selecting a file in my computer. To do it I must click Alt-Print Screen, Open Word, Create new doc, Paste document, select filename, open Browser, open dialog to attach file, find file and attach it.

I would like to:

1. press PrtScr button
2. Open the dialog to attach file
3. paste the file path and click OK

Any utility to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several utilities that accomplish this. I will give you two.

### [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/)

It is free an open source. You can set it to automatically save the screenshot to a specific folder with a specific name. You can even have it automatically copy the file path for you.

[image: Greenshot Destination]

### [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html)

The other option that I would suggest is Snagit by Techsmith. It can accomplish the same thing as Greenshot and it has a lot more features as well. This one is not free or open source tho.

Comment: yay for Greenshot  ...

Comment: Never heard about it. Greenshot is really excellent. Thanks for the suggestion. I tested it and it does exactly what I wanted and has a bunch of welcome nice features. Thanks!

Comment: ShareX is another nice screenshot tool you want to take a look at.